# ActiveModel::Serializer not returning valid JSON in rails console test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I'm relatively new to Rails, and this is my first usage of ActiveModel:Serializer. I'm just trying to set up a simple serializer and test it in the rails console before continuing. It seems to be using the serializer, but not returning valid JSON format. From the instructions I'm working off of (I'm a student), it seems I should be receiving JSON. I've been researching for the past few hours, but everything seems unrelated or goes over my head.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # User has attributes: first_name, last_name, email, password
    has_many :lists

    def full_name
        first_name + " " + last_name
    end
end
```

My UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :full_name, :email

    def full_name
        object.full_name
    end
end
```

Commands in the Rails console:

```
>> User.create(first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe", email: "test@fake.com")
>> UserSerializer.new(User.first).as_json
```

Console returns:

```
=> {"user"=>{:id=>1, :full_name=>"Jane Doe", :email=>"test@fake.com"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as_json` constructs a Ruby Hash that can subsequently be "serialized" (converted to a string) by a serialization library.

Try calling `to_json` instead. This method will return a string that can be parsed.

```
>> User.create(first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe", email: "test@fake.com")
>> UserSerializer.new(User.first).to_json

=> "{\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"full_name\":\"Jane Doe\",\"email\":\"test@fake.com\"}}"
```

Use `JSON.parse` to deserialize the string back to a hash:

```
>> JSON.parse({"user"=>{:id=>1, :full_name=>"Jane Doe", :email=>"test@fake.com"}}.to_json)
=> {"user"=>{"id"=>1, "full_name"=>"Jane Doe", "email"=>"test@fake.com"}}
```